# Get matrix from list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of (x,y,z) tuples in a dataframe A.
How can I produce a dataframe B which represents the underlying matrix of A, using the existing values of x and y as index and columns values, respectively?

Example:

A:

```
x y z
1 1 1 
1 2 10
2 1 100
```

B:

```
    1    2
1   1    10
2   100  NaN
```

Comment: What is `print(A.info())` ? Because if `x,y,z` are columns then need [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this data frame `df`:

```
   x  y    z
0  1  1    1
1  1  2   10
2  2  1  100
```

pivoting:

```
df.pivot(index='x', columns='y')
```

works:

```
       z      
y      1     2
x             
1    1.0  10.0
2  100.0   NaN
```

You can also clean the column and index names:

```
res = df.pivot(index='x', columns='y')
res.index.name = None
res.columns = res.columns.levels[1].values
print(res)
```

Output:

```
       1     2
1    1.0  10.0
2  100.0   NaN
```